# Show modal content page2 in page1[CLOSE]

Tags: jquery, html, css, modal-dialog

So i have a loginpage like this

## login.html

```
<body class="login">
    <section class="login-page">
        <div class="login-page-left">
            <div class="line-login-top"></div>
            <p>"LIFE WITHOUT<br/> CODING<br/> IT'S LIKE<br/> LIFE<br/> WITHOUT EATING"</p>
            <div class="line-login-bottom"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="login-page-right">
            <form class="login-form">
                <h2>Hi!</h2>
                <div class="line-below-hi"></div>
                <div class="input-element">
                    <div>
                        <input type="text" placeholder="username"/>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <input type="password" placeholder="password"/>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <input type="submit" value="login"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </section>
</body>
```

And i have index contain the navigation bar which navigate to login.html

```
       <nav>     
            <div class="hamburger-icon" id="toggle-menu">
                <img src="assets/images/menu.png"/>
            </div>
            <div class="nav-left">
                <h2>&lt;Coders/&gt;</h2>
             </div>
            <ul id="menu">
                <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="discussion.html">Discussion</a></li>
                <li><a href="group.html">Group</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="login.html">SignIn</a></li>                   
            </ul>    
        </nav>
```

all i want is how to show modal who contain the login(different page) when SignIn clicked.
i know how to make the modal in same page, but in another page i don't have idea what i have to do

Comment: give your modal and id and Include the modal page in your other page and then get your modal using the modal Id

Comment: can you show me how the jquery code work?

Comment: you can do something like this `var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');` it's simple, but sorry i am on the way in a car. try a bit search and you can do it

Comment: hmm, i think if that id in same page it will show, but this is at different html, are you sure that's work ?